# I install Xubuntu (kernel 5.8) on a recently bought 500Gb HD and the boot up time is ten minutes of more (AMD Ryzen 3 1200 Quad-Core 8GB)

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia, xubuntu

I have on had one graphical login.
Problem is time-outs on finding disks and timeouts on everything
I have tried boot options rootdelay=200 & rootwait which maybe help a bit
But boot up is still greater than ten minutes
from another system I can copy the /boot into new system and its over in seconds
Other errors : Initramfs unpacking failed (so I created a gzip version of ram image)
I set nomodeset in grub
As nouveau had bios in red in dmesg (and nomodeset fixed this)
I also have nvme nvme0 missing or invalid SUBNQN field
At final of boot screen flashes from graphical to text mode every few seconds
If I login to tty2 the flashed still happen and I have to get back to tty2 with the ctrl alt F2
at which stage I init 3

Comment: I would say the HD speed is very slow on Xubuntu (I changed the read-ahead to 64K from 256K) I have noted that multcount     = 16 (on) and this may be too high according to searches If I try to reduce hdparm say do not do this and makes you type in a confirm

Comment: hdparm --yes-i-know-what-i-am-doing -m0 /dev/sdb2 - trying it anyway

Comment: With multcount=0 performance is raised a bit boot up is twice as fast (~5min)
Hard drive details
description: ATA Disk
             product: WDC WD5000AVDS-6
             vendor: Western Digital
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sdb
             version: 0A01
             serial: WD-WMAV93481626
             size: 465GiB (500GB)
             capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt

Comment: searches gave me : This is a bug. To avoid delay you can use a workaround. From your terminal run:

sudo pluma /etc/default/grub

Then add the kernel boot parameter: video=SVIDEO-1:d, so it will look like this:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash video=SVIDEO-1:d"

Answer (score 0):

I used a solid state hard drive and it solved the problem.

Comment: Now it boot up in ~3 seconds